# Pass PageProps from Gatsby and Parent into Functional Component returns undefined using React and TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I have the following Functional Component. I am trying to access props from 'Pageprops' in Gatsby as well as access props from my parent. My 'data' and 'errors' is being returned from the parent.

Returning Undefined for 'data' and 'errors' but returns the correct 'path':

```
import { graphql, PageProps } from 'gatsby'

...
const Events = ({ path }: PageProps, { data, errors }) => {
```

This returns the data and errors correctly, but I don't have access Gatsby pageProps:

```
...
const Events = ({ data, errors }) => {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are declaring `{data, errors}` as second argument to your function component, but you receive only one which should be props, that's why you get undefined. you could create an interface to declare the types and pass as below:

```
interface EventsProps {
  data: any; // define type for data
  errors: any; // define type for errors
}
const Events = ({ path, data, errors }: EventsProps & PageProps) => {
```

Comment: Updated question based off your feedback...Getting a TS error back...

Comment: Your solution will run, but the TS lint is complaining at me...:/

Comment: this is llikely @Ferran said, PageProps must be an interface with some props declarations, including path. try remove path from interface `EventsProps` and declare  combining interfaces as `({ path, data, errors }: EventsProps & PageProps)`

Answer (score 2):

`PageProps` is a declarative way that uses Gatsby in combination with TypeScript to access `props`. For example:

```
import React from "react"
import { PageProps } from "gatsby"

export default function IndexRoute(props: PageProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Path:</h1>
      <p>{props.path}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

In your case, you are destructuring your `props` in subelements (`data`, `error`, and `path`). So, to access the full `pageProps` you just need to:

```
...
const Events = (props: PageProps) => {
   const { error, data, path } = PageProps
   ... 
}
```

*Note: add the required interface if needed.*

In that way, you still destructuring your `props` and keep getting access to `PageProps`.